# iOS Backup inconsistent

Tags: ios, itunes, backup, jailbreak

Situation: I do have an iPhone which I like, but no computer at home. I use the computer at work to back my iPhone up to a hard drive via iTunes. I’m willing to contemplate jailbreak or third party apps if necessary for this to happen.

The problem: I like to listen to music, my library consists of 40 gb pure, lossless music. Streaming is not an option. Sadly, my precious music is not included in the backup taken via iTunes. Indeed, the situation here seems really weird:

- Books.app on iPhone: Books added via Files.app on the iPhone are included in the iTunes Backup. Books added via the computer are not (either via sync or manually manage).
- TV.app & Music.app on the iPhone: Cannot add on the iPhone, if added on the computer it is not included in my Backup. I add my Music via manage manually when I am at my computer which is not included in the backup.

iOS: 15.7
iTunes: Most recent via Windows Store

How does iTunes exclude certain parts of the filesystem from the backup?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the operating system and version of your iTunes app and computer? [Please edit the body of the question with these details.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/446931/edit)

Comment: For 'music' [the tunes, not the app] iTunes is the 'master', the phone is the slave. Music on the phone is not synced to the computer, only music from the computer is synced to the phone. How did you get this music onto the phone?

Comment: I clarified the question, thank you

Comment: I only really know about iTunes not the others, but this is intended behaviour. The view being that as all the tunes are already on iTunes on the computer, you don't need them twice. if you do a restore, it will put them back from iTunes.